# Add required validator in div

Tags: html, angular, typescript, validation, requiredfieldvalidator

I was wondering if it was possible to put a "required" validator on a "div" ?

Let me explain: I have a list (this div) which is updated by another component. When I validate my form, I would like to check if this div is filled. If not, display a message "Contact is required"

```
div *ngIf="contacts.length > 0">
          <div fxLayout="row wrap" fxLayoutAlign="start center">
            <span class="mr-1">Contacts :</span>
            <div *ngFor="let contact of contacts; index as i" class="chip">
              {{contact.mail}}
              <i (click)="deleteContact(i)" class="fas fa-times"></i>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div *ngIf="(contacts.length == 0)">
          <div>Empty</div>
        </div>
```

When it is another component (input), I proceed like this and it works :

```
<div class="form-group">
          <label for="subject">Subject *</label>

          <input type="text" name="subject" id="subject" [(ngModel)]="message.subject" minlength="1" placeholder="Subject"
            [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && f.sujet.errors }" formControlName="subject" class="form-control">

          <div *ngIf="submitted && f.subject.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
            <div *ngIf="f.subject.errors.required">Required(1 character minimum)</div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Except that it is not possible in my current case ...

Can you help me ?

Thank you

Comment: why not use `{{contact.mail?contact.mail:'required'}}`

Answer (score 0):

I guess your goal is to use the `Form Validators` functionality. Just a quick idea:

Use hidden `<input />` field inside your Form and add binding to some `contacts` property (e.q. `length`). You can then either try to use some built-in `Form Validators` or you can build your custom one, which will check if the value of your hidden input field is greater than `0`.

Error messages you can show the same way you do for other form input fields, by checking if the input field has some validation erros:

```
 <div *ngIf="submitted && f.your_hidden_field.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
    Contacts are required
 </div>
```

Comment: how can I bind "contacts" in an input ? this is a list

Comment: I didn't write that you should bind the "contacts" list, but contacts property (e.g. `length`). Alternatively use a specific boolean property from your component - its value you can set by looking at the contacts length or similar.